# Get all inside NSDictionary into a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I got a `NSDictionary` and I want to print it into a `UITextView`.

I tried using this code, but when I try to get it into a `UITextView` it gets only one line of text, when I `NSLog` it it works perfectly.

```
for(int i=0; i<[array count];i++) {
    dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    //that shows only one line from the dictionary in the textview
    textview.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"text"];

    //that shows all the dictionary with key "text" in the log
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"text"]);
}
```

is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: When you set `textview.text` you overwrite any prior setting of that property.  So you only see the last one that's set in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should append it to the existing text

```
textview.text = @"";

  for(int i=0; i<[array count];i++)
{
        dictionary= [array objectAtIndex:i];
        //that shows only one line from the dictionary in the textview
        textview.text = [textview.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",[diction objectForKey:@"text"]]];

        //that shows all the dictionary with key "text" in the log
        NSLog(@"%@",[diction objectForKey:@"text"]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use two formatters?  Why not just `textview.text = [textview.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", diction[@"text]];`?

Comment: updated, i am more into habit of creating `NSString stringWithFormat`.. but in checking i just copied the appendingFormat, was previously going with appendingString

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `textview.text` is overwriting the previous contents of `textview.text`.

What you need to do is append the string to the existing value of `textview`:

`textview.text = [textview.text stringByAppendingString:[diction objectForKey:@"text"]];`

But this will get all the values side by side, so you may want to add a space in between the values:

`NSString *appendedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", textview.text, [diction objectForKey:@"text"]];
textview.text = appendedText;`

Finally, you can use modern Objective-C literals to access your dictionary objects like `array[i]` and `diction[@"text"]` instead of using `objectAtIndex` and `objectForKey` to type a little less.

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants the "text" values on separate lines.